# Does the DHCP server allocates static IPs?

Tags: networking, dhcp, static-ip

I have a small DHCP server with a 50 IP scope. When I try to get an IP to my device using Ethernet I get a static IP.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Please provide what device you're using, and the OS it is running on, and I can update my answer with more clarity.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. An attempt was made to edit in system information anonymously, but it wasn't clear whether this was you.  You can freely edit your own posts but for your protection, this must be done under the original user account.  If you have created a second account, that will also interfere with your ability to comment within your thread and to accept an answer.  See [Merge my accounts](http://superuser.com/help/merging-accounts) to get your accounts merged, which will solve the problem.

Answer (score 8):

A static IP is exactly the opposite of what a DHCP server handles.

You may have a static IP stored in your devices settings, without knowing the device, OS etc, I can't advise how to check.

I don't believe the following is what you're asking, but for clarification if anyone else stumbles upon this:

DHCP servers will allocate an IP address to a certain device for a certain period of time, so disconnecting and reconnecting will likely give you the same *dynamic* IP address, but this is still able to change after the lease has expired (often 72 hours but completely variable).

Alternatively, DHCP can reserve IP's for specific MAC addresses, so the IP is still dynamically allocated, but it will always be the same one. This is still different to a static IP address however.

Comment: +1. Great answer and difference between dynamic and reserved explained

Comment: It's only opposite of 'static IP' if static has come to mean 'manually configured'.